# angular 1.5 component bindings, $onChanges hook & ui-router resolves

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-component-router

EDIT: I have reformulated this question here: [angular 1.5 component, ui-router resolve, $onChanges lifecycle hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608393/angular-1-5-component-ui-router-resolve-onchanges-lifecycle-hook)

I will illustrate my question with 3 successive examples.

In the first one, a so-called *outer* component owns a *myData* object that has a *name* field. This object is passed to an *inner* component using one-way binding. The outer component exposes two methods for updating its object: *modify* that changes the value of the *name* field, and *replace* that replaces it with a new object.
When *modify* is called, the object seen in the inner component is updated because one-way binding is done by reference. When *replace* is called, the object seen in the inner component is updated too because one-way binding watches reference modification, and the $onChanges hook is called. Everything is fine here :-)

```
angular
.module('app', [])

.component('outer', {
    controller: function () {
      this.myData = {
        name: 'initial'
      };
      this.modify = (value) => { this.myData.name = value; };
      this.replace = (value) => { this.myData = { name: value }; };
    },
  template: `
    <p> outer value : {{ $ctrl.myData.name }} </p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="value">
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.modify(value)"> modify object </button>
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.replace(value)"> replace object </button>
    <hr>
    <inner my-data="$ctrl.myData"></inner>
  `
})

.component('inner', {
  bindings: {
    myData: '<'
  },
  controller: function () {
    this.nbOnChangesCalls = 0;
    this.$onChanges = (changes) => { this.nbOnChangesCalls++; }
  },
  template: `
    <p> inner value : {{ $ctrl.myData.name }} (nb onChanges calls : {{ $ctrl.nbOnChangesCalls }}) </p>
  `
});
```

In the second one (https://plnkr.co/edit/uEp6L4LuWqTJhwn6uoTN?p=preview), the *outer* component no longer declares *myData* object but receives it as a one-way binding that comes from a resolve of a ui-router component routed state. As the *modify* and *replace* methods are still done in the same way within the outer controller, everything behaves like in the previous example.

```
angular
.module('app', ['ui.router'])

.config(($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) => {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('root', {
      url: '/',
      component: 'outer',
      resolve: {
        myData: () => ({ name: 'initial' })
      }
  });
})

.component('outer', {
  bindings: {
    myData: '<'
  },
  controller: function () {
    this.nbOnChangesCalls = 0;
    this.$onChanges = (changes) => { this.nbOnChangesCalls++; }
    this.modify = (value) => { this.myData.name = value; };
    this.replace = (value) => { this.myData = { name: value }; };
  },
  template: `
    <p> outer value : {{ $ctrl.myData.name }} (nb onChanges calls : {{ $ctrl.nbOnChangesCalls }}) </p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="value">
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.modify(value)"> modify object </button>
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.replace(value)"> replace object </button>
    <hr>
    <inner my-data="$ctrl.myData"></inner>
  `
})

.component('inner', {
  bindings: {
    myData: '<'
  },
  controller: function () {
    this.nbOnChangesCalls = 0;
    this.$onChanges = (changes) => { this.nbOnChangesCalls++; }
  },
  template: `
    <p> inner value : {{ $ctrl.myData.name }} (nb onChanges calls : {{ $ctrl.nbOnChangesCalls }}) </p>
  `
});
```

In the third example (https://plnkr.co/edit/nr9fL9m7gD9k5vZtwLyM?p=preview), a service is introduced which owns the myData object and exposes the *modify* and *replace* methods. The resolve of the ui-router state now calls the service to get the data object. The outer controller calls the *modify* and *replace* methods of the service. Everything is fine until the first call to the *replace* method. I was expecting the $onChanges hook of the outer component to be triggered when the reference of the object within the service is changed but this is not the case.

```
angular
.module('app', ['ui.router'])

.factory('DataService', () => {
  let data = { name: 'initial' };
  return {
    getData: () => data,
    modify: (value) => { data.name = value; },
    replace: (value) => { data = { name: value }; }
  }
})

.config(($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) => {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('root', {
      url: '/',
      component: 'outer',
      resolve: {
        myData: (DataService) => DataService.getData()
      }
  });
})

.component('outer', {
  bindings: {
    myData: '<'
  },
  controller: function (DataService) {
    this.nbOnChangesCalls = 0;
    this.$onChanges = (changes) => { this.nbOnChangesCalls++; }
    this.modify = (value) => { DataService.modify(value); };
    this.replace = (value) => { DataService.replace(value); };
  },
  template: `
    <p> outer value : {{ $ctrl.myData.name }} (nb onChanges calls : {{ $ctrl.nbOnChangesCalls }}) </p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="value">
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.modify(value)"> modify object </button>
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.replace(value)"> replace object </button>
    <hr>
    <inner my-data="$ctrl.myData"></inner>
  `
})

.component('inner', {
  bindings: {
    myData: '<'
  },
  controller: function () {
    this.nbOnChangesCalls = 0;
    this.$onChanges = (changes) => { this.nbOnChangesCalls++; }
  },
  template: `
    <p> inner value : {{ $ctrl.myData.name }} (nb onChanges calls : {{ $ctrl.nbOnChangesCalls }}) </p>
  `
});
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

*Precision*: things are working fine when using *modify* method. However, I would like to be able to perform local copies of the binded object within the components so as to avoid modifying the original object from there (ensuring a real one-way data flow) and use the $onChanges hook to be informed of object modification (re-assignement).

*Edit*: I have come up with the following code (https://plnkr.co/edit/DZqgb4aIi09GWiblFcmR?p=preview) where the component that gets the data in the resolve is not the one that triggers the modification in the service. The question is then: why the $onChanges hook is not triggered in the *consumer* component when the data object that was resolved is reassigned ? How could this component be informed of the modification ?

```
angular
.module('app', ['ui.router'])

.factory('DataService', () => {
  let data = { name: 'initial' };
  return {
    getData: () => data,
    modify: (value) => { data.name = value; },
    replace: (value) => { data = { name: value }; }
  }
})

.component('editor', {
  controller: function (DataService) {
    this.modify = (value) => { DataService.modify(value); };
    this.replace = (value) => { DataService.replace(value); };
  },
  template: `
    <input type="text" ng-model="value">
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.modify(value)"> modify object </button>
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.replace(value)"> replace object </button>
  `
})

.config(($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) => {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('root', {
      url: '/',
      component: 'consumer',
      resolve: {
        myData: (DataService) => DataService.getData()
      }
  });
})

.component('consumer', {
  bindings: {
    myData: '<'
  },
  controller: function () {
    this.nbOnChangesCalls = 0;
    this.$onChanges = (changes) => { this.nbOnChangesCalls++; }
  },
  template: `
    <p> value : {{ $ctrl.myData.name }} (nb onChanges calls : {{ $ctrl.nbOnChangesCalls }}) </p>
  `
});
```

Ideally, the $onChanges method of the *consumer* component would be implemented this way:

```
this.$onChanges = (changes) => {
  if (changes.myData) this.myData = Object.assign({}, this.myData);
  this.nbOnChangesCalls++;
}
```

In this case, the modify version does not work (as expected because the component do not have a reference on the service data object anymore) and as the $onChanges hook is not triggered (which is my main question here!) the replace version does not work either..