# angular 1.5 component, ui-router resolve, $onChanges lifecycle hook

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-component-router

In the following example ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ChxommnERTmaULmVRNY8?p=preview)), a ui-router state routes to an *app* component that has a *data* object and a *replace* method that replaces this object with a new one using the given value. In its template, it has:

- an *editor* component which triggers the *replace* method through a callback binding ('&')
- a *display* component which receives the *data* object through a 1-way binding ('<'), makes a local copy when the $onChanges lifecycle hook is triggered, and displays the contents of the object

Everything works fine and as expected :-)

```js
angular
.module('app', ['ui.router'])

.config(($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) => {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('root', {
      url: '/',
      component: 'app'
  });
})

.component('app', {
  controller: function () {
    this.data = { name: 'initial' };
    this.replace = (value) => { this.data = { name: value }; };
  },
  template: `
    <editor on-replace="$ctrl.replace(value)"></editor>
    <display data="$ctrl.data"></display>
  `
})

.component('editor', {
  bindings: {
    onReplace: '&'
  },
  controller: function () {
    this.replace = (value) => this.onReplace({value});
  },
  template: `
    <input type="text" ng-model="value">
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.replace(value)"> replace object </button>
  `
})

.component('display', {
  bindings: {
    data: '<'
  },
  controller: function () {
    this.$onChanges = (changes) => {
      if (changes.data) {
        this.data = Object.assign({}, this.data);
      }
    };
  },
  template: `
    <p> value : {{ $ctrl.data.name }} </p>
  `
});
```

I have a problem with the following second example ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XWtW3fx5VuiTZojcnf63?p=preview)). It is the exact same setting, except that the *app* component no longer manages the *data* itself, but receives a *data* object through a 1-way binding ('<') that is defined as a resolve of the ui-router state (as can be seen in the comments, I tested both using a global object and method, and interacting through a service). When this resolved object is reassigned, I was expecting the $onChanges hook of the *app* component to be triggered (as it is for the *display* component when the data object of the *app* component is reassigned), but this is not the case. Does anyone has an explanation?

```js
let data = { name: 'initial' };
const replace = (value) => { data = { name: value }; };

angular
.module('app', ['ui.router'])

/*.factory('DataService', function () {
  let data = { name: 'initial' };
  return {
    getData: () => data,
    replace: (value) => { data = { name: value }; }
  };
})*/

.config(($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) => {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('root', {
      url: '/',
      component: 'app',
      resolve: {
        data: () => data /*(DataService) => DataService.getData()*/
      }
  });
})

.component('app', {
  bindings: {
    data: '<'
  },
  controller: function (/*DataService*/) {
    this.$onChanges = (changes) => {
      if (changes.data) {
        this.data = Object.assign({}, this.data);
      }
    };
    this.replace = (value) => { replace(value); }; /*(value) => { DataService.replace(value); };*/
  },
  template: `
    <editor on-replace="$ctrl.replace(value)"></editor>
    <display data="$ctrl.data"></consumer>
  `
})

.component('editor', {
  bindings: {
    onReplace: '&'
  },
  controller: function () {
    this.replace = (value) => this.onReplace({value});
  },
  template: `
    <input type="text" ng-model="value">
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.replace(value)"> replace object </button>
  `
})

.component('display', {
  bindings: {
    data: '<'
  },
  controller: function () {
    this.$onChanges = (changes) => {
      if (changes.data) {
        this.data = Object.assign({}, this.data);
      }
    };
  },
  template: `
    <p> value : {{ $ctrl.data.name }} </p>
  `
});
```

Comment: Hi Pierre, I'm facing this exact problem - I wonder what have you discovered since?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood, `UI-ROUTER` creates HTML with a one-time binding to `$resolve.data` on the parent scope.

```
<app data="::$resolve.data" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
  <editor on-replace="$ctrl.replace(value)" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <input type="text" ng-model="value" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.replace(value)"> replace object </button>
  </editor>
  <display data="$ctrl.data" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <p class="ng-binding"> value : initial </p>
  </display>
</app>
```

The watcher that invokes the `$onChanges` hook in the `app` component watches the `$resolve.data` property of the parent scope. It does not react to changes to the `$ctrl.data` propery of the isolate scope. And since it is a one-time binding, the `$onChanges` hook gets invoked only when the variable gets initialized and not on subsequent changes.

---

### Use a Service with RxJZ

Instead of trying to bend `$onChange` to do something for which it was not designed, build a service with [RxJS Extensions for Angular](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js).

```
app.factory("DataService", function(rx) {
  var subject = new rx.Subject(); 
  var data = "Initial";

  return {
      set: function set(d){
        data = d;
        subject.onNext(d);
      },
      get: function get() {
        return data;
      },
      subscribe: function (o) {
         return subject.subscribe(o);
      }
  };
});
```

Then simply subscribe to the changes.

```
app.controller('displayCtrl', function(DataService) {
  var $ctrl = this;

  $ctrl.data = DataService.get();
  var subscription = DataService.subscribe(function onNext(d) {
      $ctrl.data = d;
  });

  this.$onDestroy = function() {
      subscription.dispose();
  };
});
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y2hQkAC74JeY9WO1OxpV?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight. In my case, $resolve.data is the global data object (or the one that is get from the service). If I understand well, if the binding of the resolved data was 1-way rather than 1-time binding, the $onChanges hook that I expect would be invoked ?

Comment: No, the watcher invokes `$onChange` hook  when the property on the *parent* scope changes. Changes on the *child* isolated scope of the component are not watched. The `<` binding is one-way from *parent* to *child*. The `$onChange` hook reacts to changes *external* to the component. The resolver functions are only invoked once during the lifetime of a view. A one-time binding is the appropriate choice for doing one-way binding of resolver data.

Comment: But the `data`object that is resolved _is_ external to the `app` component. It is either a global variable or comes from the `DataService`. So if it was 1-way binded, I do not see why a reassignment of this object (in the global or in the service scope) would not trigger the `$onChanges` hook of the `app` component?

Comment: There are multiple *variables* referring to the same object.  When you update the reference that the *global variable* points to, it does not update what the other variables point to.  The resolve.data variable still references the old object.